# How ignore HTML elements in CSS selector that contains a specific DOM object?

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a CSS class that alters hyperlink (`a`) elements. But I want those elements which contain images (`img`) to be ignored on that class.

This is an example of the current structure of my HTML:

```
    <div class="myDiv">
    <a href="foo">  <!-- no class -->
    <img src="foo">  <!-- no class -->
    </a>
    <p></p>
    <a href="bar">TEXT</a>  <!-- no class -->
    </div>
```

I can't change the HTML structure and I can't guarantee that the second hyperlink element will be always the second.

I want to alter only the one who have just plain text.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your comment syntax is incorrect (you can see as much in the fact that the site isn't highlighting your HTML correctly).

Comment: Look at something like jQuery's `:has()` (http://api.jquery.com/has/). You can't select an ancestor by descendants with just CSS (yet).

Comment: or jQUery .not or :not , and what do you mean you can't change the HTML structure , ofcourse you can

Comment: @ScottSelby, not if he is downloading the HTML from an external widget/etc.. Not *easily* that is.

Comment: you can read it as it is being downloaded , before it is appended to the DOM , that is if you are that against jQUery

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery.
And it isn't a duplicate question, how do it change that?
The other question doesn't answer mine.